# Windows 10 not recognising System Image

Tags: windows-10

I made a System Image of my C: drive earlier, then I clean installed my computer. After that when I try to restore my computer using system image windows 10 is not recognising that image. I have used both windows instalation disc and windows->setting->recovery methods but its not recognising it.System image is located in my computers D: drive and I can still see a folder named windowsimagebackup in my D: drive. I have searched enough on google and also tried to contact microsoft support but I dont know why every time they end chat unexpectedly after 5 minutes.

Comment: You created a system image with what tool precisely?

Comment: Using Control Panel\System and Security\Backup and Restore (Windows 7)

Answer (score -1):

Since you did a clean install of Windows - which you don't need to do, I think you're confused as to what an image is for.
When you make a system image it is to restore to an HDD. This wipes out what is on that HDD.
To do that you make a restore disk/USB drive with the program you created the image with. Then you boot from that restore disk and follow your nose to restore the image.
It does not restore from windows even if you made the image with windows program.
Look and you will find the function to make a restore disk.
So at this point use the clean install to make that restore disk then boot from it an go. If you're doing this b/c the old system was flaky you're going to have the same thing when done. If so you may want to just keep working with your clean install and just copy your data from the image - some image programs won't let you do that. I use Macriun Reflect Free - very easy.

Comment: I was testing some other operating systems so I had removed windows 10 and clean installed it again after my work